# Use a dynamic variable for variables.template name

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a YAML pipeline that will serve as deploy/release pipeline for multiple environments.
Depending on the chosen environment, I would like to load a different template containing variables.
To make things more complicated, the template file is on another repo in the same project

Simple setup :

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: DataFoundation_Deployment
      type: git
      name: DataFoundation_Deployment

parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: Environment
    type: string
    default: POC
    values:
      - POC
      - SANDBOX
      - QAT
      - PRD

variables:  
    - name: varFileName
      value: "${{parameters.environment}}.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment"
      readonly: true

jobs:
- job: deploy_arm
    displayName: Deploy Data Factory
    variables:
    #- template: 'POC.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment'
    - template: '$(varFileName)'
```

This does work "- template: 'POC.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment'"
While this "- template: '$(varFileName)'" does not work, /build/deploy_datafactory.yml: File /build/$(varFileName) not found in repository https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/DataFoundation/_git/DataFoundation branch refs/heads/main version f4c504084838531d46c48d498ddbb81b42398fbd.

This isn't working either :

```
    variables:
          ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'POC') }}:
        - template: 'POC.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment'
        ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'SANDBOX') }}: 
        - template: 'SANDBOX.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment'
        ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'QAT') }}: 
        - template: 'QAT.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment'
        ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'PRD') }}: 
        - template: 'PRD.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment'
```

We would like to avoid using Variable Groups and keep everything in files in our repo.
Secrets will be fetched from a keyvault, the template file will only contain the name of the secret ;-)

Any workarounds or suggestions, to my opinion a very common setup I think.

Regards,
Sven Peeters

Dynamically loading yaml template file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable reference from:

```
- template: '$(varFileName)'
```

to the template expression syntax like below and it will work:

```
- template: '${{ variables.varFileName }}'
```

Read more about [template expression syntax and template variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax):
***Template variables process at compile time, and get replaced before runtime starts.***

See the [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax) to know more about when different variables are processed.

[UPDATE] Author does not trust it will work, so the following is the working example.

Repository: DataFoundation_Deployment, file: SANDBOX.vars.yml

```
variables:
- name: MyVariable
  value: 'MyVariableFromSANDBOX'
```

Repository: DataFoundation_Deployment, file: POC.vars.yml

```
variables:
- name: MyVariable
  value: 'MyVariableFromPOC'
```

Repository with main.yml pipeline (the original pipeline with the one line change and an additional step to echo the variable)

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: DataFoundation_Deployment
      type: git
      name: DataFoundation_Deployment

parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: Environment
    type: string
    default: POC
    values:
      - POC
      - SANDBOX
      - QAT
      - PRD

variables:  
    - name: varFileName
      value: "${{parameters.environment}}.vars.yml@DataFoundation_Deployment"
      readonly: true

jobs:
- job: deploy_arm
  displayName: Deploy Data Factory
  variables:
  - template: '${{ variables.varFileName }}'
  steps:
    - script: echo $(MyVariable)
```

Tests:
Test 1: run the main pipeline and choose POC as the Environment parameter.

Results:

1.1. pipeline prints
**MyVariableFromPOC**
[image]
1.2. the expanded pipeline/(parsed yml) in the logs contains the variable from the POC.vars.yml
[image]

Test 2: run the main pipeline and choose the SANDBOX as the Environment parameter.

Results:

2.1. pipeline prints
**MyVariableFromSANDBOX**
[image]

2.2. the expanded pipeline/(parsed yml) in the logs contains the variable from the SANDBOX.vars.yml
[image]

Comment: That's not going to work since the variable is set at runtime because it is dependant on the parameyer value. Any other workarounds to achieve the same result?

Comment: @user1627384 have you tried to change that 1 line and give it a try or read the documentation? I have supplemented the answer with the test results to prove that the suggestion works.